# Can anyone tell what I did the mistake in image encryption and decryption process using RSA

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I have split the image  into certain number of sub images and performed encryption & decryption process on each sub image . After that I have stored all the  encrypted bytes into one jpg file and decrypted bytes into another jpg file.
But I am not getting the same bytes from the decrypted file and the original image.
The code is as follows.

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
public class ImageSplitTest {
    private static final BigInteger N = null;
    public ImageSplitTest() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Shwetha\\workspace\\penguins.jpg"); // I have bear.jpg in my working directory  
        byte b[]=rsa1.readBytesFromFile(file);
        System.out.println("original image bytes"+ b);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);  
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(fis); //reading the image file  

        int rows = 2; //You should decide the values for rows and cols variables  
        int cols = 2;  
        int chunks = rows * cols;  

        int chunkWidth = image.getWidth() / cols; // determines the chunk width and height  
        int chunkHeight = image.getHeight() / rows;  
        int count = 0;  
        BufferedImage imgs[] = new BufferedImage[chunks]; //Image array to hold image chunks  
        for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++) {  
            for (int y = 0; y < cols; y++) {  
                //Initialize the image array with image chunks  
                imgs[count] = new BufferedImage(chunkWidth, chunkHeight, image.getType());  

                // draws the image chunk  
                Graphics2D gr = imgs[count++].createGraphics();  
                gr.drawImage(image, 0, 0, chunkWidth, chunkHeight, chunkWidth * y, chunkHeight * x, chunkWidth * y + chunkWidth, chunkHeight * x + chunkHeight, null);  
                gr.dispose();  
            }  
        }  
        System.out.println("Splitting done");  

        //writing mini images into image files  
        for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {  
            ImageIO.write(imgs[i], "jpg", new File("img" + i + ".jpg"));  


        }  
        System.out.println("Mini images created");  
       rsa1 rsa=new rsa1();
        BufferedImage[] buffImages = new BufferedImage[chunks];  
        byte[] decrypted=null;
        byte[] bytesImage=null;
        for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {  
         bytesImage= rsa.readBytesFromFile(new File(
                "img" + i + ".jpg"));
          //readBytesFromFile: method to read file as bytes


     byte[] encrypted = rsa.encrypt(bytesImage);    
         rsa.writeBytesToFile(new File(
                "C:\\Users\\Shwetha\\workspace\\encrypted.jpg"),encrypted );

      //writeBytesToFile: method to write as bytes

    // decrypt
         decrypted = rsa.decrypt(encrypted); 
        rsa. writeBytesToFile(new File(
                "C:\\Users\\Shwetha\\workspace\\decrypted1.jpg"),decrypted );
    }
     System.out.println("bytes from decryption"+decrypted);  
     System.out.println("bytes before encryption"+bytesImage);
}

}
```

The readBytesFromFile,encryption and decryption methods are present in rsa1 calss .

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Random;

public class rsa1 {
    private BigInteger p;
    private BigInteger q;
    private BigInteger N;
    private BigInteger phi;
    private static BigInteger e;
    private BigInteger d;
    private int bitlength = 1024;

    private Random r;
     public rsa1() {
        r = new Random();
        p = BigInteger.probablePrime(bitlength, r);
        q = BigInteger.probablePrime(bitlength, r);
        N = p.multiply(q);

        phi =   p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).multiply(q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));
        e = BigInteger.probablePrime(bitlength/2, r);
        System.out.println("e : "+e);

        while (phi.gcd(e).compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) > 0 && e.compareTo(phi) < 0 ) {
            e.add(BigInteger.ONE);
        }
       d = e.modInverse(phi);
     }

    public byte[] encrypt(byte[] image) {   
       byte[] encryptedImage = new byte[image.length];
      for (int i =0 ; i< image.length; i++){
          encryptedImage[i]= (BigInteger.valueOf(image[i])).modPow(e, N).byteValue(); 

       }   
        return encryptedImage;
    }
    public byte[] decrypt(byte[] image) {   
       byte[] decryptedImage = new byte[image.length];
       for (int i =0 ; i< image.length; i++){
           decryptedImage[i]= (BigInteger.valueOf(image[i])).modPow(d, N).byteValue();

        } 

        return decryptedImage;

        }
    public static byte[] readBytesFromFile(File file) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

           // Get the size of the file
           long length = file.length();

           // You cannot create an array using a long type.
           // It needs to be an int type.
           // Before converting to an int type, check
           // to ensure that file is not larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE.
           if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
             throw new IOException("Could not completely read file " + file.getName() + " as it is too long (" + length + " bytes, max supported " + Integer.MAX_VALUE + ")");
           }

           // Create the byte array to hold the data
           byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length];

           // Read in the bytes
           int offset = 0;
           int numRead = 0;
           while (offset < bytes.length && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {
               offset += numRead;
           }

           // Ensure all the bytes have been read in
           if (offset < bytes.length) {
               throw new IOException("Could not completely read file " + file.getName());
           }

           // Close the input stream and return bytes
           is.close();
           return bytes;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     }


     }
```

Can anyone tell how can recover my original image from the decrypted jpg file or from the decrypted bytes.

Comment: In particular, if you want to test whether or not you can encrypt and decrypt arbitrary data, you definitely don't need any image manipulation code...

Answer (score 2):

You toss away almost all information during encryption. If you perform RSA with a bit size of 1024 over an input over a single byte then the result will be 1024 bits, not 8 bits. So when you call `byteValue()` you toss away the other 1016 bits containing vital information.

As you are using textbook RSA (just modular exponentiation) your decryption method won't notice. It will just perform modular exponentiation as well, retrieving some random value, which is then fed into `byteValue()`.

You should read into hybrid cryptosystems and use RSA OAEP to create a secure protocol for image encryption. The way it currently is your protocol - including the security - is fatally flawed.